# How to create a new container with file stored in a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a volume called MYVOL, and I want to create a new container (DOCKERFILE) with specific file from that volume.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY index.php (FILE IN MY VOLUME)
volume MYVOL
```

I've been trying this code, but it copy all the files volume

Comment: So you want only mount dir `/var/www/html` of volume in your container? I think docker can not handle this.

Comment: just specify the full path to the file you want to mount instead of the whole directory. Also specify the full path where you want the file to be mounted (with filename)

Comment: `but it copy all the files volume`, what does this mean?

Comment: my path is myvol/index.php but it won't let me to do it.   it copy all the files in the volume (MYVOL)

Comment: You are confusing the concept of volume and image. Copy copies to an image. If you mount a volume on the same path you copied to, you will see the volume content, not what you copied.